# How to create instances on the fly in CDI

Tags: java, java-ee-6, cdi

Let's assume I have a Car class. In my code I want to create 10 cars. Car class has some `@Inject` annotated dependencies.

What would be the best approach to do this?

CDI has a `Provider` interface which I can use to create the cars:

```
@Inject Provider<Car> carProvider;
public void businessMethod(){
    Car car = carProvider.get();
}
```

Unfortunately that doesn't work if I don't have a `CarFactory` that has a method with `@Produces` annotation which creates the car. As much as it reflects real world that I cannot create cars without a factory, I'd rather not write factories for everything. I just want the CDI container to create my car just like any other bean.

How do you recommend I create those Cars?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use `javax.enterprise.inject.Instance` interface instead.

Like this:

```
public class Bean {

    private Instance<Car> carInstances;

    @Inject
    Bean(@Any Instance<Car> carInstances){
        this.carInstances = carInstances;
    }

    public void use(){
        Car newCar = carInstances.get();
        // Do stuff with car ...
    }

}
```

Comment: This is actually what I have ended up using. Could you fix your example, the constructor argument is not the same type as the class attribute: Car vs UIModule.

Also I think the injection should be annotetade with @New instead of @Any. And a better example for the use()-method would be one that would show how you would get an instance of the Car. For example `carInstances.get()`

Comment: @New is deprecated in CDI 1.1, in preference of @Dependent beans. See CDI 1.1, section 3.14. I don't get it really what's wrong with using a provider, i. e., `CDI.current().select(Car.class).get()` ?

Comment: @MartinAndersson The original problem was that I had to create a factory for using a provider. The example you provided in the comment is entirely new to me. Maybe you could create an answer from it?

Answer (score 10):

My favorite model for programmatic lookup is to use `CDI.current().select().get()`.

Demonstrated [here](https://github.com/martinanderssondotcom/java-ee-concepts/blob/master/src/test/java/com/martinandersson/javaee/cdi/lookup/ProgrammaticLookupRunner.java).

The servlet has a dependency on two CDI beans, one request scoped and the other application scoped:

```
private final RequestScopedBean requestScoped
            = CDI.current().select(RequestScopedBean.class).get();

private final ApplicationScopedBean applicationScoped
            = CDI.current().select(ApplicationScopedBean.class).get();
```

The test class that uses this servlet can be found [here](https://github.com/martinanderssondotcom/java-ee-concepts/blob/master/src/test/java/com/martinandersson/javaee/cdi/lookup/ProgrammaticLookupTest.java).

Examine the code and you will notice that the code is fully equivalent with what you would get using `@Inject MyBean myBean;`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use qualifiers with your `@Produces` annotations:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
public @interface MyCars {
}
```

sample-producer-method:

```
@Produces
@MyCars
public Car getNewCar(@New Car car){
    return car;
}
```

usage:

```
@Inject
@MyCars
private Provider<Car> carProvider;
```

Comment: '@New is deprecated in CDI 1.1, in preference of @Dependent beans. See CDI 1.1, section 3.14.

Comment: @MartinAndersson i know that, but as the time of the answer CDI 1.1 wasn't out, so the answer goes to CDI 1.0 (just to clarify this here)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it would be to simple not give Car any CDI scope, that makes it dependent and you'll get a new instance each time it's injected and those instances won't be destroyed until the containing instance is destroyed.

Comment: the scope isn't something to worry about, as far as i understood is that he wanted to have a injected producer and not having to implement a specific producer-class. You are right, that all injected cdi-beans become `@dependent`, but its not what palto was talking about

Comment: "a new instance each time it's injected"? How can a dependent be injected "each time"? Injection happens only once. Of a proxy. If a @Dependent bean, or proxy, was injected, then each call to this proxy will always be routed to one and the same backing bean.

Comment: It injects the proxy once, yes, but if that proxy resolves to a dependent scoped bean then that dependant scoped bean is created new on each new instance of bean requesting the injection. The injected bean becomes dependant on the life cycle of other.